# Continuous and Simultaneous read and write ble data communication

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am unable read data from ble device to android app. If I do continous and simultaneous data communication, either of the way discommunicate though bluetooth is connected.

I am trying to receive 30 bytes of data from ble device continuously. I tried with mtu size change but no use. If I start sending 30 bytes of data from app, data receiving from ble device to app, will be stopped. I am unable to do simultaneous data communication. Can someone please help me to do simultaneous data communication continuously. I am sending30 bytes of  data to ble device in the rate of 300ms and I have to receive 30 bytes of data from ble device at the rate of 1 sec.I am successfully able to read or write at a time. But not both at a time.

If I fix mtu size for 20, then I can read 20 bytes from ble device simultaneously. But I have to read 30 bytes of data from ble device.

I also wanted to know, Is there any possibility to read and write simultaneously over ble continuously without data loss?

I am doing gatt.requestMtu(512) at the time successful gatt connection.

```
 public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                gatt.requestMtu(512);
                Intent i = new Intent("status").putExtra("status",staticConnectionStatus);
                sendBroadcast(i);
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Intent intent = new Intent("status");
                intent.putExtra("status", staticConnectionStatus);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {


        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE" + ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

            byte[] charValue = characteristic.getValue();
            byte flag = charValue[0];


        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "failed");
        }

        byte[] charValue = characteristic.getValue();
        byte flag = charValue[0];
    }
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        //gatt.requestMtu(185);
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        byte[] charValue = characteristic.getValue();
        byte flag = charValue[0];

    }
};



  public void writeRXCharacteristic(byte[] value) {


        if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {


//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(200);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }

            BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000FEFB-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

            if (RxService == null) {
//                showMessage("Rx service not found!");
                broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
                return;
            }
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic RxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00000001-0000-1000-8000-008025000000"));

            if (RxChar == null) {
//                showMessage("Rx charateristic not found!");
                broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
                return;
            }

            RxChar.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
            RxChar.setValue(value);

            if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
                boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(RxChar);
            } else {
                broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            }


        } else {
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        }

    }


//Im notifying the service UUID on services discovered
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00000002-0000-1000-8000-008025000000"));
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar, true);
```

Comment: post what you have tried or done so far, this isn't enough info for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to read data from ble device, as I am receiving 30 bytes of data per second from ble device. I tried setting mtu size. But no use. Can someone please help me to read and write data  simulataneously in android@a_local_nobody

Comment: which  protocol are you using? What api are you using for that?

Comment: Most likely there's a bug in your code. Add it to the question so we can help you.

Comment: I can't see no code that enables the notification on the RX property. That's probably the main missing thing.

Comment: Additional things to change: Remove `onCharacteristicRead` as it won't be called in your case. Add `onMtuChanged` so you have confirmation that the MTU has been successfully changed. Change `setWriteType` to `setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE)` unless your device supports it and that's indeed what you want to do. It might also be a problem that you retrieve the service and characteristics on each write. Instead, retrieve them once in `onConnectionStateChange` and store them in instance variables.

Comment: I am enabling notify on services discovered. @Codo

Comment: @Codo If I set write_type_no_response I am unable to write 30 bytes of data. I will be able to send default 20 bytes of data. Thanks for response. I will try to retrieve service on connection state change.

Comment: Inspect your device with an app like nRF Connect. It will tell you wheter write with or without response is supported. And check that you haven't mixed up the RX and the TX characteristics. And what does "I am unable to write 30 bytes of data" mean? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Does it ...?

Comment: I tried with nrfConnect, there is no option to send 30 bytes of data. But can send 20 bytes of data to device using nrfConnect.I am using device and docklight tool to check data transmission.I cannot see, data displayed on docklight. If I increase requestmtu size, packets (30 bytes of data sending periodically) sending from app side will not reach docklight. If I limit the size of mtu to 20 then I can send 30 bytes of data and receive 20 bytes of data from device. But my requirement is to receive and send 30 bytes of data periodically after connection. Kindly help and Thanks @Codo

Comment: If the data is sent through notifications, you must write the cccd descriptor to enable the remote device to send notifications.

Comment: @Emil thanks for response. Im using below code                                   
  BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor=TxChar.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if (descriptor != null) {         descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        } else {
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        }    after I get first packet ,chunk of data will be displayed and then it stops sending me.But app continues to send 30 bytes periodically. Is there any android limitation to receive only 20 bytes.

Comment: setValue is not enough. You also need writeDescriptor to actually write the previously set value.

Comment: BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

      
    
        if (descriptor != null) {
         descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);


        if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
         boolean isSucess = mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);   My isSucess is always false @Emil

Comment: You may only have one outstanding GATT request at a time. Wait for the callback of the previous operation first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some comparable Kotlin code that works with a serial connection and increased MTU size. I've removed error handling, logging and some application specific code.

It uses two characteristics:
 - The *command* characteristic is used to send data from the phone to the device.
 - The *feedback* characteristic is used to receive data sent by the device.

Note the way it works:

- Creating a working connection goes through several phases and waits for each phase to complete before starting the next phase: connecting, discovering services, increasing MTU.
- Characteristics are saved in instance variables after the services have been discovered.
- The connection is ready after the callback of changing the MTU.
- Notifications are enabled after the MTU has been changed.
- Enabling notification is done with [setCharacteristicNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)). No need to fiddle with descriptors.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile

class BleConnection(private val device: BluetoothDevice) : Connection {

    private var deviceGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
    private var commandCharacteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic? = null
    private var feedbackCharacteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic? = null

    private val gattCallback = object: BluetoothGattCallback() {    
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            this@BleConnection.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, newState)
        }
        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            this@BleConnection.onServicesDiscovered(gatt)
        }
        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?) {
            this@BleConnection.onCharacteristicChanged(characteristic)
        }
        override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
            this@BleConnection.onMtuChange(gatt)
        }
    }

    // Start to connect
    override fun connect() {
        deviceGatt = device.connectGatt(null, false, gattCallback)
    }

    // The connection state has changed
    private fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, newState: Int) {
        when (newState) {
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> {
                gatt!!.discoverServices()
            }
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    // GATT services have been discovered
    fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?) {    
        for (service in gatt!!.services) {  
            if (service.uuid == Constants.SERVICE_UUID) {
                feedbackCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(Constants.FEEDBACK_CHAR_UUID)
                commandCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(Constants.COMMAND_CHAR_UUID)
                 // Increase the MTU
                 gatt.requestMtu(256)
            }
        }
    }

    // The MTU has successfully been changed
    fun onMtuChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?) {
        gatt!!.setCharacteristicNotification(feedbackCharacteristic, true)
        // ... notify that connection is fully established and ready
    } 

    // Characteristic has been changed (i.e. new data has been received)
    fun onCharacteristicChanged(characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?) {
        val data = characteristic!!.value
        // ... process the received data
    }

    // may only be called after the connection has been fully established
    // (see onMtuChange() )
    override fun sendData(command: ByteArray) {
        commandCharacteristic!!.value = command
        deviceGatt!!.writeCharacteristic(commandCharacteristic!!)
    }    
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me whether 30 bytes of simultaneous data communication is possible or not ? and I am able to read only 20 bytes data from device.

Comment: I have successfully done it. But I don't know the details of your device. It also needs to support it. Then again I get the impression that the devices is/uses a UART to BLE module (like the HM-10). If so you are dealing with a stream of data with no notion of messages or packets. So you should be able to join smaller chunks of data until you have received 30 bytes.